# Dock one panel between two others

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I have three panels:

[image: This is what I want to achieve on image]

The first one is on the top, it holds some buttons only. It will be as high as many buttons will be there.

The second ones should be directly under it, it holds a canvas that should take up most of the window.

The third one is "some kind of" status bar, it will hold some labels and data. It will be also only as high as many labels are added there.

I don't want to hardcode any sizes. So I am docking the first panel to the Top of the parent. The same goes for the 2nd panel (canvas). I am docking it also to the top. The third panel is docked to the bottom.

**I can't make the canvas(2nd panel) fill the whole space between 1st panel and 3rd panel. How to do it?**

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="700" Width="800">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="False">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <GroupBox x:Name="grBoxSettings" Header="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanelButtons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110">
                    <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>

        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <GroupBox Header="Version" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Label x:Name="lblVersion"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </DockPanel>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either use a `Grid` with three `RowDefinitions` with `Height=` 1st: `Auto` 2nd: `1*` 3rd: `Auto`,
Or Simply switch around the order in your `DockPanel`:

```
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <GroupBox x:Name="grBoxSettings" Header="Settings" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="90" Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <WrapPanel x:Name="wrapPanelButtons" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="110">
                    <Button x:Name="btnTest" Content="Test" Margin="5,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100"/>
                </WrapPanel>
            </GroupBox>
        </StackPanel>


        <DockPanel LastChildFill="False" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <GroupBox Header="Version" DockPanel.Dock="Right">
                <Label x:Name="lblVersion"/>
            </GroupBox>
        </DockPanel>

        <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" />
    </DockPanel>
```

Also, here's some documentation for the [`Dock` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.dock(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If you set the LastChildFill property to true, which is the default setting, the last child element of a DockPanel always fills the remaining space, regardless of any other dock value that you set on the last child element. To dock a child in another direction, you must set the LastChildFill property to false and must also set an explicit dock direction on the last child element.